# WebDAV (on Windows 2008 R2 IIS 7.5) is not letting me write PHP, but works with everything other file (TXT, HTM, ZIP, XYZ). Why?

Tags: php, iis, webdav, windows-server

Here is my setup:

- Windows Server 2008 R2 (latest patches, IIS 7.5)
- WebDAV enabled on a virtual directory in IIS

I can connect to the server from an outside network and upload/download/delete a .txt file just fine. I can do the same with .htm, .html, .zip, .xyz. No problems, no errors.

When I try to do the same with a .php file, I get a 405 error for PUT and I can't upload the damn files.

I know it's got to be a setting somewhere that is just blocking the PHP extension. Anyone know where it could be?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I had to intercept the handling of the .php extension by the WebDAV handler before my PHP53_via_FastCGI handler got to it first.

1. Go to your virtual directory with WebDAV enabled on it in IIS.
2. Search for and go to Handler Mappings.
3. Click "View Ordered List" on the right side pane.
4. Move WebDAV to the top of the list above any PHP extension. Ignore any warnings about not being inherited from the parent handlers.

Problem solved.